# Creation of textbook-and-exercises tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Following the apparent consensus in the [previous discussion about an "homework-like" tag](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/424/55), and the lack of objections there, I went ahead and created [textbook-and-exercises](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textbook-and-exercises).

I tagged a few questions with it, just to get the ball rolling and see if we agree on the way it should be used.

I quickly put together the following tag excerpt:

> *Applies to questions of primarily educational value - styled in the format similar to that found in textbook exercises. This tag should be applied to questions that are (1) stated in the form of an exercise and (2) at the level of basic undergraduate and postgraduate textbooks.*

I don't particularly like it, but I guess it's a start. Feel free to improve it, and let me know if you agree with its stated intent.
Similarly, let me know if you have alternative proposals for the name (for example I personally wouldn't mind creating some synonym with a shorter name, if only to make it quicker to add).

Comment: Nice! regarding shorter synonym, I could understand that "homework" is pejorative but would that be the spirit of the tag?

Comment: Follow-up question/food for thought: Should the rules about duplicates differ for such questions?

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 are you thinking about something in particular?

Comment: @glS I don't think so - it appears to me that (some of) the most common types of duplicates are actually these sorts of questions - they're usually very similar, but not *exactly* the same, so it's left me wondering if we should get the OP to try and piece together as much as possible, or if we should more strictly follow the 'only *exact* duplicates are duplicates' idea

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 I've always considered questions duplicates when I find it likely that the OP would have got his answer in the other question if they saw it. Yes I guess for exercise questions this often means that duplicate questions can be slightly less similar on the surface if relying on the same calculations or tricks. This approach usually works I'd say, especially paired with comments: you ask the OP for further clarification to distinguish the questions from the other, and if you don't get any (as is often the case in these questions) go ahead and VTC as duplicate